# What's the correct way to create a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Edit (as commented: XY-Problem) - Problem:**

I want to create my own control which has predefined styles and positions for special elements (Button,...), but in general everything should be able to be placed inside my custom control. The custom control in my case is just a "menubar" which should be able to be used anywhere in the "GUI code" - but there is no need it has to be there. But *when* it is used it should be the same style and behavior everywhere. A style is - I think - not enough, because there are also predefined elements in this menubar (e.g. Help is already in menubar)

**Edit end.**

I want to build a custom control (just a special stackpanel) in WPF with the following requirements:
can be used as any other control within a xaml
has defined styles for controls within the custom control

First I simply tried to create a UserControl containing a stackpanel with defined styles (in the xaml) for containing elements (e.g. Button). This UserControl contained the

```
<ContentPresenter />
```

in the xaml. With this method it is not possible to name the containing elements. E.g.:

```
<mynamespace:MyStackPanel>
  <Button Name="w00t">This does not work!</Button>
</mynamespace:MyStackPanel>
```

Next try was to create a "real" custom control. This custom control is just a class without the xaml. Code is very simple. Class inherits from UserControl and just contains:

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Children.Add(new ContentPresenter());
this.AddChild(sp);
```

Woooohoooo, now it's possible to name the containing elements. But still a big problem: How to define the styles?

I could define the style for my very own custom control in a ResourceDictionary. But i have to add the ResourceDictionary to the global (App.xaml) Resources. And then I can define styles only for my custom control - not for the containing elements? - But anyway... doing it like this just feels wrong!

So the main question is: WHAT is the "correct" way of creating a custom control which can be used in xaml like any other control? If the second way is the correct way - how is it possible to set the style like I do it in a xaml (e.g. every Button in this element has a special style) and has it to be a "global" ResourceDictionary?

How is it implemented in third-party stuff?

Comment: Why do you want to "name" stuff to begin with?

Comment: You can use the `x:Name` property when you cannot use the `Name` property`, but as @HighCore said, why would you want to do that? To answer your question, the 'correct' way to create a `CustomControl` can be found in the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: The elements has to be named so I can use them in the code behind - e.g. dynamically create a TabView.

Comment: And if you want to style UI elements inside a container, just add Styles for those UI elements (such as `<Style TargetType="Button.../>` to the container's `Resources`, such as `<MyStackPanel.Resources><ResourceDictionary Source="MyStyles.xaml"/></MyStackPanel>` or something.

Comment: @marty `The elements has to be named so I can use them in the code behind` - wrong. Don't manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.

Comment: Sheridan x:Name also won't work... @HighCore - where to put MyStackPanel.Resource if there is no MyStackPanel-xaml?

Comment: @marty you don't `dynamically create` the UI in WPF. Instead, you define a proper DataModel or ViewModel and use `DataTemplate`s to LET WPF Dynamically present the appropiate UI for the underlying Data.

Comment: @Marty I think you might just have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) here. Can you edit your question and add a specific use case example or something?

Comment: @HighCore do you think there is absolutely no need to be able to name elements?

Comment: You still need to name UI elements to access them in XAML `DataTrigger`s, etc., but *not* from code behind.

Comment: @HighCore there are certainly reasons to have names. Animations/Storyboards in particular require names. Not being able to name the content of UserControls is a highly complained about issue with WPF: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/483024/wpf-error-message-cannot-set-name-attribute-value-0-on-element-1-1-is-under-the-scope-of-element-2-which-already-had-a-name-registered-when-it-was-defined-in-another-scope

Comment: @marty only if you're using them in XAML, not in code. Code behind practices are discouraged in WPF. `x:Name` is still useful when you need `ElementName Bindings` or `Trigger SourceName` or animation related type of stuff, though.

Comment: @mikez I know that, however I must make it clear that code behind type of stuff is discouraged. see my above comment

Comment: @HighCore Edited my question to make my problem more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I made an example for you, which involves `Custom Controls` (as Opposed to `UserControl`s)

**Step 1:**

Create a new class (code only, no XAML) derived from `ContentControl` (or whatever UI element that has a behavior similar to what you need)

```
    public class ReusableContainer : ContentControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Button", typeof(Button), typeof(ReusableContainer), new PropertyMetadata(default(Button)));

        public Button Button
        {
            get { return (Button)GetValue(ButtonProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

See how I'm defining the `Button` property as a DependencyProperty here. You can add more DPs for whatever "content placeholders" that you need in your custom control.

**Step 2:**

Have your predefined Styles for the UI elements inside the container in a separate `ResourceDictionary`:

`CustomStyles.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Step 3:** in `app.xaml`, define an application-wide style for the `ReusableContainer`, which defines it's template:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication14.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication14"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ReusableContainer}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ReusableContainer}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomStyles.xaml"/>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Button}"/>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

See how I'm using the `TemplateBinding` expression to define that the `ContentPresenter`'s content is going to be defined by the `Button` property in the `ReusableContainer`.

Also notice how I'm Adding the Resources in `CustomStyles.xaml` to the `ControlTemplate.Resources` collection. This makes these resources available to all UI elements inside the Template.

**Step 4:**

Place your ReusableContainer in a Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication14"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:ReusableContainer>
            <local:ReusableContainer.Button>
                <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Hello! Button 1"/>
            </local:ReusableContainer.Button>
        </local:ReusableContainer>

        <local:ReusableContainer>
            <local:ReusableContainer.Button>
                <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="Hello! Button 2"/>
            </local:ReusableContainer.Button>
        </local:ReusableContainer>

        <local:ReusableContainer>
            <local:ReusableContainer.Button>
                <Button x:Name="Button3" Content="Hello! Button 3"/>
            </local:ReusableContainer.Button>
        </local:ReusableContainer>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This indeed solves my issue (for templates within my control). But I will wait before accepting the answer, because I'm still not sure if this is the beste way to create custom controls... :)

Comment: @marty I still see an XY problem here. Why would you want to define specific styles for UI elements ONLY inside this container? doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I thought it would make sense, that Buttons in the menubar look the same all over the Application and not let all the parts over the application decide on it's own which style should be used. I'm not sure if this conceptionally correct...

Comment: @marty what is this MenuBar you're talking about? Is it only Buttons? If so, I strongly recommend using a ViewModel-first `IEnumerable<ICommand>` approach, instead of a View-First approach where you define each MenuBar in XAML.

Comment: the content of the menubar will be more than buttons (combobox...) but the main point is, that it's not the same content all over the application - just like the ribbon in ms outlook.

Comment: You probably want to add property change handlers for your child control properties in order to add/remove the child elements from the parent's logical tree. They will be loaded into the visual tree via inclusion in the template. As to applying custom styles to certain child controls, take a look at how the WPF ToolBar is implemented. Specifically, look at how it uses custom style keys to define contextual styles that are then applied within the control (e.g., a `Button` or `ComboBox` looks different when placed in a `ToolBar` than it does elsewhere).